# SharedViewModel from koin not working with MapFragment

Tags: android, koin

The sharedViewModel is not being recognized:

```
class MyMapFragment: MapFragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by sharedViewModel()

    private var map: GoogleMap? = null

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        map = googleMap
        map?.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this)
    }

    override fun onMapLoaded() {
    }
}
```

Is this a known issue? I couldn't find anything. By the way, it works with a "regular" fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In koin there are 2 extension files `FragmentExt` for `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` wich offer the extension function `sharedViewModel()`. 
`MapFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment` and therefore the extension function is not available there.

You can use `SupportMapFragment` which extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and includes your desired extension function instead of `MapFragment`